# Apex Trigger not working on After Insert

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforce1-app, mobile

I am new to this forum so please forgive me if I'm not entering the question to the right channel.
We have voice files being attached to Attachments in Tasks.
I am trying to copy the voice attachment to Chatter Feed for it to be available in the Salesforce Mobile App and be able to listen to the audio file.
The problem I am facing is that the trigger will not fire if set to After Insert.

Here is the code below that I am using.

```java
trigger AttachFileToChatterFeed on Attachment (after insert) {    
    List<ID>attlist = new List<ID>();

    for (Attachment att : trigger.new){
        //check for audio files only
        if(attachment.ContentType = 'audio/wav' ){
            attlist.add(att.ParentId);
        }
    }
    
    list<Task>Tasklist = [Select Id, from Task where Id IN : attlist];
    list<FeedItem> listOfFeedFiles = new List<FeedItem>();  
            
    for(Task t : Tasklist){
        if(t.Type == 'Call'){
            FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
            post.ParentId = attachment.ParentId;
            post.Body = 'A voicemail was left';
            post.Type = 'ContentPost';
            post.ContentData = attachment.body;
            post.ContentFileName = attachment.Name;
            post.Title = attachment.Name;
            listOfFeedFiles.add(post);
        }
    }
    
    if(listOfFeedFiles != null){
        insert listOfFeedFiles;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Your code is not correct: you are referencing a variable named `attachment` which you have not defined.  Please [edit] your post to include code that will compile correctly.

Comment: Your code wont compile, how did you manage to deploy this even?